# Formulas are suddenly not recognising formulas returning null value as blank cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a sheet which has formulas and conditional formatting based on cells containing formulas which used to work perfectly and now does not.  The faulty formulas are looking at cells which are empty/not empty and basing their results on that.

The cells they are looking at contain formulas which return a blank or a string of text.

Is excel somehow now recognizing the formula rather than the result?

I have an archive copy of the sheet where the formulas all worked perfectly but enough significant change has been made elsewhere to put me off re-using this, but I've checked the sheets and the formulas are all identical.

I've tried simplifying it down to `=IF(E10<>"","TEXT","BLANK")` and it always returns `TEXT`, even though the formula in E10 is returning a blank.

If relevant, the formula in E10 is-

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP(C10,INDIRECT($D$2&"SA!"&"$R:$T"),3,FALSE),"")
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that `VLOOKUP(C10,INDIRECT($D$2&"SA!"&"$R:$T"),3,FALSE)` is throwing an #N/A error?

Comment: try `=IF(TRIM(CLEAN(E10))<>"","TEXT","BLANK")`

Comment: Does is help if you replace `E10<>""` by `NOT(ISBLANK(E10))`?

Comment: @Dominique OP already stated that E10 has a formula.  `ISBLANK()` will always return false if there is a formula even if it returns `""`.

Comment: If your lookup returns a space (`" "`) it may appear as blank, but it's not. You can verify that with LEN().

Comment: @P.b: that problem can be solved, trimming the content of the cell.

Comment: True, that's a way to fix it, but LEN can be used to verify it.